# Querying documents by fields in an array

Tags: mongodb

In MongoDB I have a collection of documents called 'clients', where each document is structured roughly as follows.  Note that TimeStamp is a DateTime:

```
{
  "Sessions": [
    {
      "SessionId": "pojiu5iprr2xw5ucsudyrkpv",
      "LocationId": {
        "$oid": "4de4590bfcee1a1b44165e2b"
      },
      "Timestamp": "Wed, 01 Jun 2011 09:39:26 GMT -04:00"
    }
  ],
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "4de6410efcee1a1204a3326c"
  }
}
```

I'd like to be able to query for "all clients which have at least one session with a timestamp in the last 24 hours".  Is this possible without resorting to a full M/R scan? I will also accept answers with a statically defined Date, e.g. "all clients which have at least one session with a timestamp later than 1/5/2012"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about adding a field to the main document for "latest session time".

**Updated:**
Ok, here's how you can do it without adding a new field/index:

```
db.clients.find(
   { "Sessions" : 
      { $elemMatch : 
         { Timestamp : { $gt : new Date(new Date() - 86400000) } } 
      } 
   } 
);
```

same code on a single line:

```
db.clients.find({ "Sessions" : { $elemMatch : { Timestamp : { $gt : new Date(new Date() - 86400000) } } } } );
```

86400000 is the number of milliseconds in a day.

Comment: That's my backup plan. I'd rather not have to duplicate data.

Comment: Think of it as a way of indexing. That's all indexes are, in reality--duplicate data.

Comment: Sure. I just want to stay out of the index writing business if I can.

Comment: Ok, updated my answer. Looks like it's possible with $elemMatch. You might want to add an index on "Sessions.Timestamp"...